# Another algorithm for stable matching?

Tags: matching, stable

The only algorithm I have seen to compute a stable matching is the one by Gale an Shapley. Is there any other algorithm to compute a stable matching?

Comment: This seems a little vague without specifying what properties you would hope an additional algorithm to have.

Comment: I was not looking for any particular property. Thanks for the answers below. I will look into them. It is a bit unfair to select an answer, so after checking the provided references, I may end up flipping a coin to select a random correct answer...

Answer (score 7):

There is a totally different algorithm due to Subramanian which uses a fixed point approach. The first idea is to represent the knowledge that we have at any given point in time using *intervals*, which represent which women each man is considering, and vice versa. Using ideas similar to Gale-Shapley, we keep shrinking the intervals. In contrast to Gale-Shapley, this algorithm is symmetric with respect to gender. Eventually a fixed point is reached, and we can read the man-optimal and woman-optimal matchings. Subramanian found a neat way to implement this using three-valued logic and comparator networks. Check out for example [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.2721).
Subramanian's approach was later elaborated by Feder.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a polynomial-time algorithm to find any stable matching.

Understanding the algorithm requires you to study a *rotation poset*.  One of the good materials to learn the rotation poset is this book.

[Dan Gusfield, Robert W. Irving: The Stable marriage problem - structure and algorithms. Foundations of computing series, MIT Press 1989](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/stable-marriage-problem/)

Answer (score 4):

There is also a small set of linear constraints that form a polytope whose extreme points are the stable matchings. This allows you to find a stable matching optimizing any linear objective using linear programming. See Vande-Vate 89 ("[Linear Programming Brings Marital Bliss](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~avis/courses/360/2013/ktlaerid/LP-bliss.pdf)"), or Vohra 12 for a different treatment ("[Stable Matchings and Linear Programming](http://www.currentscience.ac.in/Volumes/103/09/1051.pdf)")